# Qiskit PrimitiveOp compose function giving weird output

Tags: qiskit, programming

I am executing the following code.

```
[ins] In [1]: from qiskit.opflow.primitive_ops import PrimitiveOp
     ...: from qiskit.quantum_info import Pauli
     ...: import numpy as np
     ...: x = 3.5*np.sqrt(3.0/2)
     ...: print(x)
     ...: annih_op=PrimitiveOp(Pauli('X')) + 1.0j*PrimitiveOp(Pauli('Y'))
     ...: creat_op = PrimitiveOp(Pauli('X')) - 1.0j*PrimitiveOp(Pauli('Y'))
     ...: my_op = x*creat_op.compose(annih_op, front=True)
     ...: print('type(my_op) = ', type(my_op))
     ...: print('my_op)= ', my_op)
```

It gives a warning and a very deeply nested numpy array.

```
    4.286607049870561
<ipython-input-1-583b34f24f0c>:8: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from nested sequences exceeding the maximum number of dimensions of 32 is deprecated. If you mean to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  my_op = x*creat_op.compose(annih_op, front=True)
type(my_op) =  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
my_op)=  [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[PauliSumOp(SparsePauliOp(['I'],
                                              coeffs=[4.28660705+0.j]), coeff=1.0)]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]






























 [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[PauliSumOp(SparsePauliOp(['Z'],
                                              coeffs=[4.28660705+0.j]), coeff=1.0)]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]






























 [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[PauliSumOp(SparsePauliOp(['Z'],
                                              coeffs=[4.28660705+0.j]), coeff=1.0)]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]






























 [[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[PauliSumOp(SparsePauliOp(['I'],
                                              coeffs=[4.28660705+0.j]), coeff=1.0)]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]
```

But if I set `x` to be something else for example 2.0, I am getting the expected output and no warning.

```
[nav] In [2]: from qiskit.opflow.primitive_ops import PrimitiveOp
         ...: from qiskit.quantum_info import Pauli
         ...: import numpy as np
         ...: #x = 3.5*np.sqrt(3.0/2)
         ...: x=2.0
         ...: print(x)
         ...: annih_op=PrimitiveOp(Pauli('X')) + 1.0j*PrimitiveOp(Pauli('Y'))
         ...: creat_op = PrimitiveOp(Pauli('X')) - 1.0j*PrimitiveOp(Pauli('Y'))
         ...: my_op = x*creat_op.compose(annih_op, front=True)
         ...: print('type(my_op) = ', type(my_op))
         ...: print('my_op)= ', my_op)
2.0
type(my_op) =  <class 'qiskit.opflow.primitive_ops.pauli_sum_op.PauliSumOp'>
my_op)=  2.0 * I
+ 2.0 * Z
+ 2.0 * Z
+ 2.0 * I
```

Is it a possible bug in Qiskit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you checked the type of your coefficient `x`, you will find that its value is `numpy.float64`.
And if you checked how multiplication by scalar is implemented in `PauliSumOp` class <sup>[[1](https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/opflow/primitive_ops/pauli_sum_op.html#PauliSumOp.mul)]</sup>, you will notice that only scalars of type `int`, `float`, and `complex` are supported. Otherwise, the multiplication by scalar will be handled by the primitive class (`SparsePauliOp` in our case) which inherits `__rmul__` from `MultiplyMixin`<sup>[[2](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/main/qiskit/quantum_info/operators/mixins/multiply.py)]</sup>. This is where the issue happens.

So, to avoid the issue, just cast your coefficient,

```
x = float(3.5 * np.sqrt(3.0/2))
```

Or change the order of multiplication,

```
my_op = creat_op.compose(annih_op, front=True) * x
```

Comment: Is this a bug? Should this be reported to Qiskit developers?

Comment: It should be considered as a bug.

Comment: I raised an issue. https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit/issues/1452